# Trying to change the name of a foreign key column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, alter-table

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Collaborators (
  CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(25),
  LastName VARCHAR(25),
  Street VARCHAR(50),
  City VARCHAR(50),
  State VARCHAR(25),
  ZipCode INT,
  Telephone VARCHAR(15),
  PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
  SKU VARCHAR(20),
  Description VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID));
```

My goal is to change any instance of "Customer" to "Collaborator". I tried to go one at a time and use an alter table statement.

```
ALTER TABLE Collaborators CHANGE CustomerID CollaboratorID INT;

ALTER TABLE Orders CHANGE CustomerID CollaboratorID INT;
```

Here is the error code MySQL spits out at me:

> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './QuantigrationUpdates/#sql-668_24' to './QuantigrationUpdates/Collaborators' (errno: 150)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've figured that I can't simply change the column names because they have key constraints, but I don't know how to work around that. Thanks.

Update: Am I able to use CREATE VIEW to work around the key constraints?

Comment: Drop before and recreate the constraints afterwards?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are not the same engine and use different SQL dialects. Remove the tag for the one you are **not** using.

Comment: What is SKU and description (not that it's any of our business)

Comment: Hmm, [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=965d9df290b60a5cf59c6c9cdc27a334) (though I had to change the table name in your statements back to `customers` because that is the table you showed the DDL for). I also wouldn't know that one cannot rename referenced or referencing columns. The relationships aren't usually stored by names but internal IDs. And the error message also doesn't point in that direction. Must be something else that's causing the error with you, I believe.